# How to debug libtool executable in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, libtool

I have an Autotools + libtool project and I am trying to setup Qt Creator for it.

I created project via `Import project --> Import Existing Project`. Building (`make`) and running the specified executable works fine, but when I try to debug I get error

```
not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `libtool --mode=execute gdb your_program` for debugging, see http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html

For Qt Creator you can create a script

```
#!/bin/bash
exec libtool --mode=execute /usr/bin/gdb "$@"
```

to specify it in `Options --> Build & Run --> Debuggers` (and select the debugger on the `Kits` page after that)

[image]

Also check `Run In Terminal` in the project run settings

[image]